# How does wolfram alpha compute this sum of exponentials?

Tags: summation, exponential-function

I have been breaking my head from morning, but I have not been able to understand how wolfram alpha obtained the relationship.

[image: Wolfram Alpha]

[Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation+of+n%3D0+to+n%3DN+e%5E%284n%29)

Comment: Have you heard the term "geometric series"?

Comment: Hint: $a(1+a+a^2+...+a^n)=a+a^2+...+a^{n+1}=(1+a+...+a^n) + (a^{n+1}-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a general fact $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^N r^n=\frac{r^{N+1}-1}{r-1}$$

Try proving this by induction. Then just let $r=e^{4}$

Comment: @saraswathivasudevan If you think I helped you, you can click the check mark to mark this question as "answered". Or you can wait until a better answer comes by.

Comment: Is proving it by induction easier than without?